# Generating table of contents

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I posted this one a couple of months ago on the Mathematica newsgroup, but got no usable response. I thought I'd give SO a try.

The question was: I don't seem to be able to find the method to generate the table of contents of a
Mathematica document I'm working on. Anyone knows this feauture's
hideout?

David Annetts pointed me in the direction of the AuthorTools, an old v5.1
utility package that's still hidden in Mathematica. However, it
doesn't work on my document (v7). Any clue?

**Edit**
The TOC should contain correct section numbers (if present in the stylesheet) and list page numbers (this requires taking page size settings into account).

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps looking at the code of Yuri Kandrashkin's package, [Sidebar](http://sites.google.com/site/qstate/), will be useful?

Comment: Great tip, I'm evaluating it now. At the moment, I seem to have some problems with the section numbers. All chapters get the same number. I also don't get page numbers. Perhaps the package works only for the default style sheet?

Comment: If you look at the code, in TOC.nb there is a function getNotebookInfo. It starts with styles = "SectionStyles" /. $TOCSettings, and earlier there is $TOCSettings = {
  "SectionStyles" -> {"Section", "Subsection", "Subsubsection"},
  "LockingOptions" -> {Deletable, Selectable, Editable},
  "RemovingOptions" -> {Deletable, Selectable, Editable, 
    CellChangeTimes}}. So I guess it should be reasonably easy to modify this (but I have neither tried nor actually read carefully the code to see whether it may break or not).

Comment: +1 Seems a very nice package. Is it full compatible with Mma v8?

Comment: @belisarius: it seems to work for me, but I don't use most of its features so maybe some parts actually don't.

Comment: I've looked somewhat closer in the TOC code and it doesn't do any pagination as far as I can see. I  also didn't see any handling of automatically numbered section headings. So, it's a nice package, but it doesn't do what I want.