# Initialization command

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I noticed in the `Cell > Cell properties` menu an item I assume was recently added, but I really wouldn't know for sure (8.0.4/Win here). It's called `Initialization Command`:

[image]

Nothing about it to be found in my documentation center. Neither does it seem to be in the [online reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/WorkWithInitializationCells.html):

[image]

Any idea what this is supposed to do? As far as I can see its effect is the same as the Initialization Cell menu item.

Comment: I can say, that under MacOSX-x86-64 this menu entry is not available. A quick search brings me only to the Workbench Doc under http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/loadingfiles.html

Comment: In my v.8.0.4  under Windows I have no Initialization Command.

Comment: Do you have any packages installed that might be adding this?  I don't see it, and it seems unlikely to be the sort of thing that would be given a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: In my v.8.0.4 under Macintosh, there is indeed an Initialization Command with the same shortcut. I cannot distinguish it from the Initialization Cell command, which it sets.

Comment: @brett I thought I hadn't but then I remembered I installed a package to investigate an answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185843/generating-table-of-contents . I'll check ASAP. Not at home right now

Comment: @BrettChampion : yow were right, the culprit was the [Sidebar package][1] that I installed long ago and that I forgot about since. On a different note: the 4th menu item in my installation ("deployed") also differs from the one in the docs ("active") even after removing Sidebar.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185843/generating-table-of-contents

Comment: I think you should close this question and/or post your comment above as an answer and Accept it.